Excel VBA - Having issue with Embedded chart Line width After ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=
After copy pasting a embedded chart using vba
using below command to reassign the data range for each chart, when using below command chart's Line width going back to default width, Can I stop this width change ?
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("BND1!$A$" & CStr(b) & ":$EZ$" & CStr(b) & ", BND1!$A$" & CStr(s) & ":$EZ$" & CStr(s) & ", BND1!$A$" & CStr(v) & ":$EZ$" & CStr(v) & ", BND1!$A$2:$EZ$2")

I tried to change the width with the below command, that is not happening, but no error message, Pls let me know how I can change, Thanks in advance.
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
   .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
   .Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
End With


Are you sure the chart is active at the time you are manipulating the line weights? Are you manipulating the correct Full Series Collection object? Maybe loop through them instead?

Try this command before the line that changes the chart's source data:
ActiveWorkbook.ChartDataPointTrack = False

This turns off the 'Properties Follow Chart Data Point' setting, and preserves any custom formatting you've applied to the chart. If the setting is true, custom formatting is blown away when the source data changes.
I wrote about this property here: Properties Follow Chart Data Point.
